# Converting mesh object to lamp shape

Tags: modeling, lighting, scene

I have a simple scene here:
[image]

I want to convert the scaled torus object to a lamp object. I don't want to use shaders because then it will only emit light from it's surface. I want it to be like an area light emitter if that is possible. Is there any way I can do this?

My question is to convert a mesh object to a lamp object as represented in yellow.

Comment: Does an area light emitter also not only emit light from its surface?

if you want to just use an area light, you can create a texture of your circle shape, and then put that into the shader of the area light.

Comment: I want the lamp itself to have the torus shape

Comment: I still don't understand your reasoning for why you can't use shaders.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27: Your Q is not clear. Please give as more details. Do you want lamp cast torus shape light as in my A or you just want to let lamp be represented in viewport as torus shape? Or torus shape is OK to light a scene, but you don't want to appear in render (as Lamp object)?

Answer (score 3):

Lamp lightning torus shape

[image]

Blending can be changed by Lamp Properties > Size

[image]