# How to change the shape of a spotlight in Eevee?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to make a spotlight project a square onto the wall in Eevee, but I can't find an easy way to do it. Right now I kinda have a jimmy-rig where I made a cube and put a square-shaped hole in it, then moved it in front of the light. This is really hard to move around though and I would like it to work as it does in Cycles with nodes. Is this possible? Or should I stick with my jimmy-rig?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167004/2214

Comment: The question is not solved. All links suggest only cycle, but not eevee solution.